# Write a program that generate part of this sequence 122333444455555

Tags: kotlin

Write a program that prints a part of the following sequence 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 ... (the number of repetitions is equal to the respective number). Input is a positive integer n – the number of the elements of the sequence that the program should print. Output the sequence of numbers, written in a single line, separated by spaces. The idea here is to use while loop instead of for loop.

For example, if n is 7, the program should output 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 (seven numbers).

> SAMPLE INPUT: 8
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT: 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4

I tried to write this code:

```
fun main() {
    val input = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var counter = 0
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    while(i <= input) {
        while(j <= i) {
            counter++
            print("$i ")
            j++
        }
        i++
    }
}
```

> But instead of getting 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
> I get this output 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Check this  : https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFsIGlucHV0ID0gNVxuICAgIHZhciBjb3VudGVyID0gMFxuICAgIHZhciBpID0gMVxuICAgIHdoaWxlKGkgPD0gaW5wdXQpIHtcbiAgICAgICAgdmFyIGogPSAxXG4gICAgICAgIHdoaWxlKGogPD0gaSkge1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgY291bnRlcisrXG4gICAgICAgICAgICBwcmludChcIiRpIFwiKVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgaisrXG4gICAgICAgIH1cbiAgICAgICAgaSsrXG4gICAgfVxufSJ9

Comment: `i`, `j` and `counter` are all counters. Give them descriptive names and you’ll have an easier time doing this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    
    val input = readLine()!!.toInt()
   var counter = 1
   var i = 1
   var j = i
    while(counter <= input) {
     j = i
     while(j > 0 && counter <= input) {
        print("$i ")
        j--
        counter++
    }
    i++
}
    
}
```

Another solution with O(n) time complexity.

```
fun main() {

    val input = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var counter = 1
    var printed = 0
    var currentNumCount = 0
    while (printed < input) {
        print("$counter ")
        printed++
        if (currentNumCount < counter - 1) {
            currentNumCount++
            continue
        } else {
            currentNumCount = 0
            counter++
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### My solution to this task

```
fun main() {
    val input = readln().toInt()
    var num = 0
    var count = 0
    while (count < input) {
        repeat(num) {
            if (count < input) {
                count++
                print("$num ")
            }
        }
        num++
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).